# Android adding information to a table when the alarm started

Tags: android

Hi stackoverflow users I have the next problem:
I have created a program that compare in a countdown timer 2 values( a feedback and a counter )
The counter is the value I set of the temperature for example and the feedback another value I get from outside.

When the countdown timer reach 0 if the counter is not equal with the feedback value the alarm start and I want to add the feedback and the counter to a log.

Example of a small piece of code is below, here I compare the counter with

```
if(Integer.parseInt(feedback.getText().toString()) != midvalue)
                     {
                            btnbool.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                            btnbool.setText("FALSE");  
                            showup.setText(""+counter);
                            letme = 2;
                            if(alarmapornita == 0)
                            {
                                alarmapornita = 1;
                                handler.post(thread);
                            }
                            alarma = 1;
                            myhandler.post(mythread);
                            healthy = false;
                            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Log.class);
                            i.putExtra("mymidvalue",midvalue);
                            i.putExtra("myfeedback",Integer.parseInt(feedback.getText().toString()));
                            startActivity(i);
                     }
```

The problem is that with Intent I get only one entry to the table and when I get the alarm on it switch to the other activity.
I don't know anything else how to use, is there any option to replace intent ?

Comment: What's table here? database table?

Comment: It's just a tableLayout

Comment: Please post your whole code and explain your requirement more clearer. Then only I can help.

Comment: My whole code have like 800 lines of code, you don't want to read it trust me and I have english variables, my questions was clear, how can I parse values when I press a button for example without switching the activity and I want that activity to use that values adding them into a Table Layout.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you have more than one values to be sent to next activity?

Comment: Yes I have only 2 values to be sent, I just thinked, is there a way to call a function that is on my second activity from my main activity, the function will have 2 parametters. ?

Comment: See you can call any public method present at second activity from your first activity, but it will not update any data on your second activity to be shown on Table Layout.

Comment: I have 2 buttons, a textview and a edittext. I increment or decrement a value from textview ( let's say default is 20 ) if when countdown timer reach 0 from 10 seconds let's say and I have a different value on that edittext than textview I want them to be added in a second activity into a log.That log is build with a tableLayout.I want max 10 entryes to be added on that tableLayout.

Comment: Instead of doing like this: while count down counting your time please store the value on SQLite or any interanl storage. When you'll goto to Activity 2 retrieve those values and show on Table Layout. Else use getter setter class model to store and then pass those data via intent. No other way to pass the data to second activity.

Comment: Please mark resolved to my answer below so that other can take benifit of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as per our discussion, followings can be solutions to your query:

While count down counting your time please store the value on SQLite or any interanl storage. When you'll goto to Activity 2 retrieve those values and show on Table Layout. Else use getter setter class model to store and then pass those data via intent. No other way to pass the data to second activity.

Please mark it as resolved so that other can take benfit from our discussion.

Comment: I have done an integer array and parse it whit intent when pressing the button. more eassilly